# Custom Activity Indicator Issue

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiactivityindicatorview

I am making an iPhone app in which I have made a custom activity indicator class to show an activity indicator animating on another class, but my problem is that the activity indicator class get start animating but it doesn't get stop animating.

Here is the code:

```
customActivityView   = [[ CustomActivityIndicatorView alloc] init];
        customActivityView.view.center = self.view.center;
        [self.view addSubview:customActivityView.view];
        [customActivityView.activityIndicator startAnimating];  // is work fine to add a custom activity indicator and start animating 
[customActivityView.activityIndicator stopAnimating];  // but this line doesn't work
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that `customActivityView.activityIndicator` actually returns the activity view, or quite likely, if it returns anything at all.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot start and stop an activity indicator in the same method.if you do so you cannot see anythng in result.

Comment: Sorry I am not doing start and stop an activity indicator in the same method. I have just written the code below for stop animating but I try to stop it in another method.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry it's working now actually my custom Activity class was get assign two times that why it didn't stop.